# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Helper.ConfigurationHelper'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm

I have two simple poco classes in my models folder I want to use entity framework to create a migration.  I also have a dbcontext class, which is the instance I want to use as my migration.

When I try to run: dnx ef migrations add IntialCommit

I get the following error Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Helper.ConfigurationHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Even though i have the right package, (Microsoft.Framework.Configuration)

Any Idea why i'm getting this error?

AnimalsContext.cs

```
public class Animalscontext :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Animalscontext> animals  { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dog> dog { get; set; }

}
```

Animals.cs

```
     public class Animals
        {

            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public List<Dog> dogs { get; set; }
}
```

Dog.cs

```
 public class Dog
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string breed { get; set; }
}
```

project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  }
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<Animalscontext>(DbContextOptionsBuilder => DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Output

```
Using context 'Animalscontext'.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Helper.ConfigurationHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.JsonConfigurationExtensions.AddJsonFile(IConfigurationBuilder configuration, String path, Boolean optional)
   at WebApplication2.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv) in C:\Users\JConterio\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2\Startup.cs:line 21
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(Type startupType, IList`1 diagnosticMessages)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.get_ApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DbContextOperations.TryCreateContextFromStartup(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.AddMigration(String name, String context)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.<>c__DisplayClass7_6.<Main>b__15()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Main(String[] args)
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Helper.ConfigurationHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Comment: You use proably the nightly build. Did you tried on Beta8?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using `1.0.0-*` unless your intention is to test the nightly build.

Try to use specific package like `1.0.0-beta8` which have been released and tested. To ensure you are using the latest package, change your references and try again. If you have VS2015, make sure to update your tooling to Beta8 too.

This should fix most of your problems. Otherwise, try a "File > New Project" with the latest Beta and compare your `project.json` file.

Comment: i currently am using tooling beta7, ill try to update to 8 now. I changed the 1.0.0-* to the latest that the nuget offered, and still nothing.  lets hope the tooling beta8 works. thanks